# Codeigniter inline attachment not appearing

Tags: php, codeigniter, inline, attachment

I am trying to send this email with an inline image but the image is always sent as a real attachment: Content-Disposition: attachment.
Any ideas?

```
$config['protocol']  = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'mail.mydomain.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 25;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'noreply@mydomain.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
$config['mailtype']  = 'html';
$config['newline']   = "\r\n"; 

$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->from('noreply@mydomain.com', 'Mydomain');
$this->email->to('email@mydomain.com');       
$this->email->subject('Subject');  

$image = getcwd() . '/image.jpg';
$this->email->attach($image, 'inline');
$message = '<!DOCTYPE html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title></title></head><body>';
$message  .= '<img src="cid:' . $image . '" /><br /><br />';
$message  .= 'Hi there!<br /><br />';
$message  .= '</body></html>';
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->send();
```

Comment: Have you extended your email class?

Comment: No. Why should I? All the features I'm using exist on the native Email class.

Comment: In my case the image is not appearing/attaching. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: No.. I haven't used the image.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line after loading the `email` library.

```
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
```

Comment: It's there: `$config['mailtype']  = 'html';`

Comment: Sorry for late reply and `$this->email->attach()` is used to sending files with email as attachment. remove it then you won't send the image.